# Are isolated points of a set by definition part of the set?

Tags: general-topology

My book defines isolated points in contradistinction to limit points, which the author detfines thus:

> Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $X$. A point $b \in X$ is called a *limit point* of *A* if every neighbourhood of $b$ contains a point of $A$ different from $b$.

Which I take to mean, "is a limit point if for all neighbourhoods of $b$, there exists a point $x$ such that $x \in A$ and $x\ne b$". Meaning, that $b$ need not be in $A$ to begin with, something I think makes sense in light of a subsequent theorem demonstrating that the containment of all a set's limit points is a necessary and sufficient condition for the set to be closed. Of course, if all sets necessarily contained their limit points, then they would all be closed, something I don't believe is true.

Now for isolated points, he writes:

> "A point $b$ is an isolated point of a set $A$ if there exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $b$ such that N contains no ***other*** points of A"

(emphasis mine). I can't help but to interpret this as, "there exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $b$ such that for all $x \in N$, $x \notin A$ or $x = b$ and $b \in A$", which is close to but not quite the negation of the antecedent of the definition a limit point, the true negation being: $\sim\forall_N\exists _{x \in N}(x \in A \wedge x\ne b) \iff \exists_N\forall _{x \in N}(x \notin A \vee x= b)$.

I believe the negation alone allows for the case that $x \notin A$ for all $x \in N$. This would then lead to the strange conclusion that the closure of $A$, here defined as the union of limit and isolated points, may contain points not in $A$, since as $X$ is an open set, it may be possible to find such a neighbourhood for which all $x$ in the neighbourhood are not in $A$, satisfying the disjunction.

Furthermore, I would very much like it to be true that all isolated points of a set are in the set, since I have just used that to-be-determined fact in a proof.

Comment: Interesting.  In my experience, the definition should have started "A point $b \in A$ is an isolated point of $A$ if...."

Comment: This would also be strange, since, for instance, $0$ would be an isolated point of $(1,2)$.

Comment: You are correct.  Isolated points *are* in the set.  I suspect the author assumed that was known but .... you are correct.  As it is stated that definition is not correct.  It alone would imply the points *not* in A that are not on the border are isolated points of A which would be a worse than useless classification for those points.... (such as $0$ being an isolated point of $(1,2)$ as Randall points out)

Comment: "This would then lead to the strange conclusion that the closure of A, here defined as the union of limit and isolated points...." such a definition here would mean the closure of $A$ would actually be the entire Universal space!.... Example $\overline{(1,2)} = \mathbb R$ because all points in $(-\infty, 1)$ or in $(2,\infty)$ are "isolated points" of $(1,2)$.

Comment: My feeling is that "limit point *for* A" is preferable to "limit point *of* A", although I have yet to see a book adopt this convention. As for "contains no other points of A" in the second definition, from the English language point of view, I think "**...other...**" carries implicitly the information "b is in A". But Randall has given an easy way to make the definition crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the definition of an *isolated point of $A$* is sloppy.  As Randall comments, the definition should more precisely be

> A point $b \in A$ is an isolated point of $A$ if there exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $b$ such that $N$ contains no other points of $A$.

Clearly, *no other points of $A$* means *no other point of $A$ than $b$*. But unfortunalety the author defines

> A point $b$ is an isolated point of $A$ if there exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $b$ such that $N$ contains no other points of $A$.

There are two possible interpretations:

1. *no* ***other*** *points of $A$* means that the authors **implicitly assumes $b \in A$**, but does not explicitly mention it. This is certainly his intention, but it is rather sloppy. The precise variant would be to write $N \cap A = \{b\}$.
2. *no other points of $A$* has to be understood as *no other points of $A$ except possibly $b$*, i.e. $N \cap A \subset \{b\}$. This would be a highly non-standard definition because it also allows $N \cap A = \emptyset$.